# how to creat a magnifier glass(rectangular) in canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I developed a software which its aim is to provide a visualization to the user with in tkinter canvas. now I need a magnifier pane appear and  moves along with the course. is there any way to do that? any clue how to create a magnifier glass in canvas?

Comment: Were you able to create a magnifier glass? Can you share?

Comment: unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple magnifying glass program using "pywin32" and "pillow" library.
I hope this helps.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import win32gui

def zoom_open():
    global top, canvas
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.overrideredirect(True)
    top.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    top_frame=tk.Frame(top, bd=1)
    top_frame.pack(fill='both')
    canvas = tk.Canvas(top_frame, width=194, height=194)
    canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    magnifier()

def magnifier():
    global imgtk, top
    x, y = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2][0], win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2][1]
    top_posx = x-215
    top_posy = y+15
    if top_posx < 0:
        top_posx = x+15
    if top_posy+250 > screen_height:
        top_posy = y-215
    top.geometry(f'200x200+{top_posx}+{top_posy}')
    zoom_rect=x-10, y-10, x+10, y+10
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=zoom_rect, all_screens=True)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img.resize((200,200)))
    canvas.itemconfig(canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=imgtk))
    top.after(50, magnifier)

root = tk.Tk()
button=tk.Button(root, text="magnifier", command=zoom_open).pack()
screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(78)
screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(79)
root.mainloop()
```